# How to attach a file.txt or anything in hourmailer python

Tags: python, email

So I'm having a struggle how can I send an attachment in email by using the hourmailer because that is what my project for. Basically what I just really want is to pass my txt file or any file maybe but text file will be fine with some messages on it. Here is the code

```
import requests

url = "https://hourmailer.p.rapidapi.com/send"

subject = str(input("Enter a subject:"))
email_origin = str(input("Enter a Origin email:"))
email_html_file = str(input("Enter the HTML file name:"))
  
# open the file to be sent 
filename = "{email}".format(email=email_html_file)
attachment = open("C:\PythonItems\Email\{email}".format(email=email_html_file), "rb")


payload = {
    # "toAddress": "nellyordona@gmail.com",
    "fromAddress":email_origin,
    "toAddress": "jumo.vicentillo.sjc@phinmaed.com",
    "title": subject,
    "message": "Hi, I'm from {email}".format(email=email_origin),
    "attachment":attachment.read()

}

headers = {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "............",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "hourmailer.p.rapidapi.com"
}


response = requests.request("POST", url, json=payload, headers=headers)

split = response.text.split(":")[1][:-1]
if (split == '"Message sent to {text}"'.format(text="jumo.vicentillo.sjc@phinmaed.com")):
    print("Message sent to {text}".format(text="jumo.vicentillo.sjc@phinmaed.com!\n"))
    print("All messages sent!")
```

As you see here in `attachment.read()` it doesn't work...it says that json `Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable` 
at the code of `response = requests.request("POST", url, json=payload, headers=headers)`

How do i fix this thing about attachment and json thing?

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the attachment with the `"rb"` (read, binary) flag and trying to convert the resulting bytes object to a JSON string with `.read()` method.
What you should instead do is omit the `b` flag or decode (e.g.: with `.decode('utf-8')` method) it before passing it on.

But in your case, I'd wager HourMailer API **does not support** attachments anyway due to the lack of any specific `/attachment` URLs or documentation.

Comment: nvm about this thing..I have question.. Can I change sender email in HourMailer API ? Please reply asap thanks.

Comment: because the sender email is `no-reply@hourmailer.com` as you can see here 
https://rapidapi.com/blocklabs-blocklabs-default/api/hourmailer

Comment: You'll have to create a new question for a new question. But I doubt HourMailer can do that.